# Is the Laplacian operator and divergence operator commutable on the 2D riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am trying to derive the Green function of the poroelastic media on a 2D membrane. Here I encounter a general math problem.

In 3D space, We know that the Laplacian operator and divergence operator are commutable, which means that:
$$D^{\beta}D_{\beta}D^{\alpha}v_{\alpha}=D^{\alpha}D^{\beta}D_{\beta}v_{\alpha}\quad(1)$$
where $D_{\alpha}$ is covariant derivative and $v_{\alpha}$ is a vector in terms of its
covariant. However, we know that the differential operator is not commutable on manifold given that Christoffel symbols do not always vanish. So I am not sure about the eq. (1) is still valid or not on an arbitrary 2D manifold(i.e. spherical surface)? If not, what is the correct relation between the left side and right side of the equation? In other words, what extra term should we put there to correct the equation on a 2D manifold?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hint:$$(D_bD^bD_a-D_aD_bD^b)v^a=D^b((D_bD_a-D_aD_b)v^a)-(D_aD_b-D_bD_a)(D^bv^a)$$

Comment: So as there is only one nonzero element for the Riemann-Christoffel tensor in 2D, I assume the equation is still valid, right?

Comment: I don't see how that follows. You can compute the commutator, and it will contain some curvature-dependent terms.

Comment: For a spherical surface, the first term in I get -K div(v), the second term is -K div(v), too. so the two terms canceled out.

Comment: There should also be a term proportional to $\operatorname{div}(Kv)$, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: yes, the second term is exactly zero, and the first term is -div(Kv).